# Python Kafka Consumer doesnt receive any messages when set to latest and received same message if set to earliest

Tags: python, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

```
from kafka import KafkaConsumer,KafkaProducer 
   consumer = KafkaConsumer(bootstrap_servers=['IP:9092'],auto_offset_reset='earliest',
                             consumer_timeout_ms=3000,enable_auto_commit=True,
                              group_id='group39assignment')
    consumer.subscribe(['group39logs'])
    for event in consumer:
       print(event.value)
```

I have the above code created to consume messages from a Kafka topic from a python program.

- When I set the offset to earliest it keeps receiving the same message again and again
- when I set it to latest I don't receive any message at all.

What I want is to just get message once I start my Kafka consumer from python code.

Please let me know where i am going wrong?

Comment: What library are you using? Confluent (based on librdkafka) or Kafka-python? Also, are events constantly produced to the topic or there is a static amount of them?

Comment: I am using the kafka python one. added to question. this is a POC so only static amount

Comment: if it reads from latest it expects to pull only messages that will come after it started. Try starting with reading from latest (and keeping same consumer group) and produce couple messages.

Comment: It did not help. I already tried.

Comment: I'm not that much familiar with `python-kafka`, but in confluent package I'd expect additional call to start pull data after subscribing. 

`c.subscribe(["topic_name"])


while True:
    msg = c.poll(1.0)`

Answer (score 1):

The auto offset reset is only applicable if there has been no committed offsets for the given group id.

Since you've enabled auto commits, then there's  likely a committed value, which will always be used when the consumer starts. If it always consumes "the same" values, then it's not consuming *enough* records to auto commit, and so you'd need to commit manually (and best to disable auto commits if you do commit manually)

When the consumer starts at the latest offset, then it's waiting for a producer to send new data. If there's no producers, then of course it'll show nothing

Comment: Can you please let me know what i need to change in code for offset latest? Sorry I am very new to this

Comment: You said you already tried it. Read the documentation for possible values for `auto_offset_reset`